# have a file in the classloader's root path, how to create it

Tags: java, file, classloader

```
File f = new File(path)
```

How to give the path parameter in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the question: if you already have a file, why do you want to create it? And what's the problem with `path` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
    URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("config.properties");
    File f = new File(resource.toURI());
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you need to know from where the classloader loads its resources. This is classloader-dependent, and most types of classloader don't use files at all. If you have an URLClassLoader (which fortunately is quite often), you can ask it about its URLs, and look if there is one `file:` URL. Then use this URL as a base.

If your Classloader has no `file:` URL, obviously you have no chance.

But I think most probably you are not doing the right thing - what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a better option and go for `java.net.URLClassLoader`.

This class loader is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs referring to both JAR files and directories.

A `URLClassLoader` can be used to load classes in any directory.

Check out [this example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/LoadClass.html)

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory containing the class file
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

---

Also, have a look at [File ClassLoader in Java](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/file-class-loader/)